# Are Black Holes high and low entropy?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, entropy, singularities, gravitational-collapse

Some time ago I read that without knowing more about quantum gravity
the assumption that Black Holes continue to collapse is valid.

That mystifies me somewhat but for the purpose of this question I’m going to say we found a Black Hole that is fully mature and the singularity is as small as it’s going to get.

I would like to know about the entropy of Black Holes because in my logic a singularity has low entropy.

At the same time we know that Black Holes contain most of the entropy in the observable universe. So, apart from the singularity the Black Hole is very evenly distributed.

Does gravity prevent the singularity’s entropy from increasing?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics): “The second law of thermodynamics requires that black holes have entropy. If black holes carried no entropy, it would be possible to violate the second law by throwing mass into the black hole.“

Comment: A search on arxiv.org for “black hole entropy” yields about 4500 papers.

Comment: @safesphere If you want to have a personal theory that black holes have zero entropy and violate the second law, no one can stop you. But in mainstream physics, black holes have entropy proportional to the area of their horizon. (It is *not* a fourth parameter and does *not* violate “no-hair”.) My recollection is that Bekenstein had a number of thought experiments that made the entropy-area connection clear, even before Hawking’s calculation. When we travel to a black hole, perhaps we can do some real experiments to see if he was right.

Comment: @safesphere On the other hand, it would neither surprise nor disturb me if there were no such experiment possible. I am perfectly happy *ascribing* a particular possibly-unmeasureable entropy to a black hole in order to preserve the Second Law for the measureable entropy outside it. In any case, I believe the area of the horizon *is* measurable in principle, so one can simply *define* the entropy as 1/4 the area and preserve the Second Law, without thinking about what is happening inside.

Comment: Happy to pay taxes for someone like Hawking or Bekenstein. Check the Gravitation book by MTW and read the preface, which is dedicated to taxpayers :)

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.07727.pdf?